# How can i convert this CURL code to python, i have multiple files to download

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

```
curl -F user=aditya -F password=1234 -F date=20220516 -F format=csv -F report= sales -F type=IT -F family=SAAS -F  version=4 https://www.yahoo.jsp > file.zip
```

Note: I have changed the data here but format is same, I need the file to be downloaded from website and saved it in my Desktop, I have 4 classification of files under which multiple subclassification is there?

Comment: You will have to provide more information. 
1. Does this code (with the right data / credentials) work?
2. What are the 4 classifications you are talking about?
3. Is there a pattern to the filenames?

Comment: I usually use https://curlconverter.com/